# Can I get place names and variable labels from the census API?

Tags: python, census

I am using the Census wrapper in python to pull data from the Census API to Pandas. Does anyone know of a way to get the variable labels and the place names through the API? I set it up with a dictionary of the two names and the variable names for each tracts and variable, and then mapped them onto the dataframe after the query. But that seems like that should be redundant and I should be able to get that information from the query. any ideas?

Right now it looks like this (there are actually 25+ variables, and about 25 tracts) looking at demographics:

```
census_variables = 'B02001_001E,B02001_002E,B02001_003E'
variable_labels = {'B02001_001E':'Estimate!!Total','B02001_002E':'Estimate!!Total!!White alone', 'B02001_003E':'Estimate!!Total!!Black or African American alone'} 
# variable:label

tracts = ['170100', '170200']
tract_named={'170100':'REVERE', '170200':'REVERE'}
# tract:town

and then a loop to do the queries and add them to the dataframe.
for t in tracts:
    result = c.acs5.get(('NAME',census_variables), geo={'for': 'tract:{}'.format(t),
                       'in': 'state:25 county:025'},year=2018)
    df=df.append(result,ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone comes across this question: the census has a slack channel on the [development page](https://www.census.gov/developers/). I posted the question there and got a quick answer. They are very helpful over there for any questions on the API.